# How to scroll an EditText with listview to the very top of the layout in fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml

How to scroll an EditText with listview to the very top of the layout when keyborad is up on focus EditText in fragment?

i desgin a custom spinner with edit text and listview and have almost five spinner in the Scrollview i want when i click on edittext then edit text and its list scroll up and full visible in the screen

what happen with me you can see on screen shot the list is not fully visible and it has fixed height.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple
you just have to place your recyclerview/listview and editTex field inside ScrollView add add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in your recylcer view and you are good to go!

Sample Code:

```
<ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_toolbar">

          <EditText
               android:id="+@id/editText"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
           

          <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:itemCount="5" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this is not working i need auto scroll the view when keyboard is up

Comment: add  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` in your `<activity>` tag of manifest.xml file may be it works

Comment: added in manifest but it is not working in fragment i also use this on fragment
getActivity()?.getWindow()?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

Comment: did you try `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Comment: yes i also try NestedScrollView with Coordinate layout which is also not working